# Graphics package not formating text correctly

Tags: java, string, graphics, formatting

I have a couple classes that are performing some functions at the beginning, which write to csis.txt.  Afer that I have a window pop up to display what is in csis.txt WITH formating.  However the it is not formating correctly.  Here is what I have:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver extends Canvas {


public Driver(){
    setSize(200, 200);
    setBackground(Color.white);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("csis.txt"));
    MFQ mfq = new MFQ(pw);
    mfq.getJobs();
    mfq.outputHeader();
    mfq.runSimulation();
    mfq.outStats();
    pw.close();
    Driver GP = new Driver();


    Frame aFrame = new Frame();
    aFrame.setSize(1000, 1000);


    aFrame.add(GP);

    aFrame.setVisible(true);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    try {
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("csis.txt"));
        String s = fileScan.nextLine();
        for (int i = 20; fileScan.hasNext(); i += 20) {
            g.drawString(fileScan.nextLine(), 0, i);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

csis.txt:

http://pastebin.com/Ynh6jqYk

Sidebye side of csis.txt and graphics window not formating correctly:

[image: side by side]

Comment: _it is not formating correctly_. Can you explain why? What does it do? What did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Avoid using `paint` from a top level component like `JFrame`. The paint requirements for these are generally more complex then for a normal component and they're not double buffered
2. You must call `super.paintXxx` to ensure you honour the complex paint chain
3. Try avoid loading resources within any `paintXxx` method, these should return as fast as possible so as not to slow down the paint process
4. The output is an issue with the using a variable width font. To means that each individual character has its own width. Instead, you need to try and use a fixed width font instead.

Check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Take a look at

- http://www.lowing.org/fonts/
- http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts
- http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts

For some font suggestions...

Instead of drawing directly using `Graphics`, you could load the text into a `JTextArea` or `JTextPane`.

Take a look at [How to use text compnents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) for more details

I'd also be tempted to parse the input and load it into a `JTabe`

See [how to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a monospaced font to achieve this. Try adding these lines right before the `for` loop in the `paint` method:

```
Font f = this.getFont();
g.setFont(new Font("monospaced", f.getStyle(),f.getSize()));
```

Hope this helps, it works for me.

---

As MadProgrammer noted, you shouldn't override the `JFrame#paint` method. Use a JPanel instead and override its `paintComponent` method to perform custom painting.